# Add line break to static block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

Magento's CMS static block creator automatically trims off extra whitespace, including line breaks. The static block that I'm currently creating is a little close to the element beneath it and I would like to add a line break, but have only managed to do it by adding this at the end:

```
<p style="color:white">.</p>
```

Obviously, this is very hacky and should probably be avoided. What is the proper way to accomplish the effect of a line break in a CMS static block.

I'm sure I can accomplish it by wrapping the whole thing in a class and creating a margin-bottom in CSS, but I think there must be an appropriate way to do this within the static block.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. A non-breakable space should work:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.